# Где надо вставить .lower() чтобы бот принимал любой регист букв?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

```
@bot.message_handler(chat_types=['private'], func=lambda msg: msg.text in [
    'свойства степени', 'степень', 'свойства степеней', 'преобразование степеней'])
def pythagoras_theorem(message: types.Message):
    photo1 = open('png/shk-1355-osnovnyie-svojstva-stepenej-kornej-1x1.png', 'rb')
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo1)
```

Comment: `msg.text.lower() in ...`

Comment: спасибо помогло,сделайте как ответ,закрою тему

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В функции проверки сообщения переведите текст в нижний регистр:

```
@bot.message_handler(
    chat_types=['private'],
    func=lambda msg: msg.text.lower() in [
          'свойства степени', 'степень', 'свойства степеней',
          'преобразование степеней'
    ]
)
def pythagoras_theorem(message: types.Message):
   ...
```